# Adding labels to points plotted on world map in R

Tags: r, label, ggmap, world-map

I have plotted a series of latitude/longitude coordinates on a World Map using R. I would like to add labels to these points that I have plotted.
Currently my code is:

```
library(maps)
cities<-read.csv("cities.csv", header=T)
cities
                  id  lat   lon
1            Nigeria  7.0   6.0
2             Gambia 13.3  16.0
3           Cambodia 12.0 105.0 
4             France 46.0   2.0  
5             Greece 38.0  23.7

map(database="world")
points(x = cities$lon, y = cities$lat, col = "red", pch=20)
```

I want to add either a label (cities$id) or number each of the points in order so I know which point corresponds to which of my data entries.

I have seen codes with **ggplot2** but I cannot install **ggmap** (perhaps my version 1.0.44 is too old) so am trying to stay away from this approach.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

[World map with unlabeled points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulAJC.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R `text` function, add after the `points` call:

```
text(cities$lon, y = cities$lat, cities$id, pos = 4)
```

You can change the `pos` to suit: 1 shows text below the point, 2 to the left, 3 above and 4 to the right.